# I used cin to get a string input as shown below in the code and it works fine. Is it alright?

Tags: string, c++11, fgets, cin, gets

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   int n;
    char s[15];
    cin>>n;
    cin>>s;
    cout<<n*2<<"\n";
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried with gets and fgets function but they don't work just after cin..

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of confused on what you are asking here, but I have noticed something here that can be fixed.

Yes the code you have compiles and it works. However, it could be improved. 
 When prompted to input something to your `char` array, you'll notice that it will not accept whitespaces. So if I input, `Jon Smith`, the output will only be `Jon` and the rest of the string input is cut off.  To fix this, you will need to make a call the the `getline()` function.

The [documentation of `getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) states:

> Extracts characters from *is* and stores them into *str* until the delimitation character *delim* is found (or the newline character, '\n'..)

This will allow you to get whitespaces from the input and put the entire input back into a `string`.

If you add this function call to your code where the second input prompt lies and you were to run the code, you would notice that you will only get prompted once and then the program would finish running *before* the second prompt *appears* to be executed. This is because `getline()` does not ignore leading whitespace characters and it stops reading any further because the `cin>>` before it is seen as a newline character.

To make `getline()` work with `cin>>`, you must use `cin.ignore()` before the call to `getline()`.  Below is some code that I wrote to make this adjustment:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    string s; //using string allows us to use getline()

    cout<<"Enter a number: "; //Let user know they are being prompt for number
    cin>>n;
    cin.ignore(); //ignore the leading newline

    cout<<"Enter a string: "; //let user know being prompt for string
    getline (cin,s);

    cout<<n*2<<"\n";
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

Again, the code you have works and compiles.  I'm not sure if my solution is the answer you are hoping to get but I hope that you are able to find this useful! Cheers!

Comment: Sure.. Thanks .. :D